# How to create custom smart contract using Python Flask on custom BlockChain

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

I am planning to create one smart contract but I am not able to grasp how to do it in Python flask, all I see about is how to do it in etherium.

I have already created one custom blockchain with:

1. Nodes - mine, add transaction, broadcast and more
2. BlockChain - for each nodes to maintain their local blocks
3. Wallet - Each node having wallet to maintain their amount
4. Transaction - To have transaction record in ordered way and having hash functions and more

But Right now I want to try to create one smart contract from scratch on my custom block chain but I am not sure how to do it. I am new in this field so any help on this ?

I just want to be able to use any one of the smart contract feature in my custom block chain without using etherium.